# Redirect main domain to subfolder with question mark

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect my main domain to this url which is under the main domain http://cupofertas.com/?s=&dir-search=no&post_type=ait-dir-item

My problem is when I try to access any other page with a question mark on the url like /?p=23 I get redirected again.

Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?cupofertas.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?s=&dir-search=no&post_type=ait-dir-item
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?s=&dir-search=no&post_type=ait-dir-item$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?cupofertas.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /?s=&dir-search=no&post_type=ait-dir-item [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your first rule and keep only this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?cupofertas\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /?s=&dir-search=no&post_type=ait-dir-item [L,QSA]
```